# What are your favourite TikZ/PGF answers?

Tags: discussion, tex-sx-package, publicity

I proposed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/766853#766853) that we put together a "Best of TikZ on TeX-SX" package.  There have been some really neat answers to problems developed on the site, and I think it would be nice to put them together in to some sort of easily usable state.  My reasons are:

1. It's easier to download a single package/style file than to cut and paste a load of code from here, there, and everywhere into ones preamble.
2. Some of the code could do with a bit of polishing (for example, putting in to a macro, hiding internal bits) that are standard when making a package, but not when posting an answer here.
3. **Publicity:** Ideally, these would get used and the people who used them would find out about us.

By doing this as a collective venture, I hope that:

1. It is a real *community* project.  I'm not so naive that I think that loads of people will do the necessary work, but hopefully lots of people will see what's going on and at least feel as though it's based on the community's collective work.
2. It isn't loads of work for any one person.  Most of the stuff I'm thinking of is already workable, so I'm hoping it won't take too much work to put it together.
3. This is only the first of many ...

On that last note, I'm picking TikZ because it's the area I think I've contributed most to.  Also, there's a reasonable volume of TikZ answers here to choose from, and a good number of people contributing them.

**First Steps:** We need some code to put in the package, and some volunteers willing to take part.  I think that we can adapt the SE software to gather all that information here! So:

1. If you like or dislike the idea, vote on **this question** accordingly.
2. Propose (and link to) TikZ/PGF answers on the main site that you would like to see in such a package in answers to this question, one link per answer.  Also vote for those you like (but the people who volunteer to put it together will have the final say).  Please bear in mind that to be worth putting in a package, it has to be something that you can envision being used several times.  **Proposing your own answers** is not only acceptable but actively encouraged.  If, when reading an answer, something occurs to you as a possible improvement, please make a note of it (just the idea at this stage).
3. In **one** answer, we can collect names of volunteers who are willing to do a bit of extra work polishing the answers.  I'll start this off, make it CW, and "accept" it (when I can) to ensure that it is easily distinguished from the rest.

---

Template for proposals

```
### TikZ/PGF Answer:

### Brief Description:

### Possible Improvements:
```

---

Further discussion on this topic is available here:

[TikZ/PGF answer package, Part 2](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1248/)

Comment: this is great! let us know if there's anything the community team can do to assist.

Comment: @Andrew: Your acceptance won't make it stay on top; that doesn't work for self-accepts.

Comment: @Hendrik: Didn't know that!  Nonetheless, the important thing is to distinguish the _volunteers_ answer from the rest and "accepting" it will at least do that.

Comment: @Hendrik: I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew: Do you want me to make the answer or the whole thread a CW?

Comment: @Martin: Whoops!  I forgot to make that answer CW (done).  As for the whole thread, I don't see any advantage in it being CW, but I don't see any disadvantage either.

Comment: @Martin: On second thoughts, I thought of a use for CW mode so, yes please hit it with Mjolnir.

Comment: I also have some other TikZ solutions I was planning to publish as part of a bundle. They are no questions here on TeX.SX which ask about it (yet) (but with great foresight I already coded them ;-) ). One would add more anchors to existing standard node shapes like rectangle, like `east north east`, for points at 25% and 75% of the height and width.

Comment: @Martin: If you're pondering including them in this, I'd say that that was fine.  So long as the majority come from TeX-SX then I think that adding a few extra is fine.  You could always tell me what they are and I'll ask a question for you!

Comment: @Martin: I definitely want to see your idea about the extra nodes for standard shapes, I needed something exactly like that earlier today and ended up using coordinate calculations. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/add-more-anchors-to-standard-tikz-nodes

Comment: this is an interesting project.  in my opinion, it could use a manual (which i will volunteer to proofread).  and when it's done, i would like to solicit an overview article for tugboat.

Comment: @barbara: Thanks for your support and offer of help.  At the moment, the project is proceeding in more of a piecemeal way than as one huge project (in particular, I don't think we'll ever declare it "done"!).  The first "package" is already on CTAN (braids) and I have a couple of others that just need polishing.  Other things keep getting in the way!

Comment: @Andrew -- even if it's piecemeal, there will probably come a time when it reaches a critical mass.  i'd like to reiterate my suggestion to present it, when it reaches that point, in a tugboat article.  although i recognize a lot of tugboat readers among the members of tex.sx, there's still likely to be a residue that haven't yet found there way here.  some free publicity wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Volunteers

- [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)
- [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)
- [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/83)

Comment: I would volunteer, but I don't think I'd be any use. I can offer to test the package, though...

Comment: Same here. I don't have any experience with making packages, but I would like to help with testing and documentation, if required.

Comment: @Jake: Neither do I (except small trivial packages), but you do have good knowledge of TikZ/PGF. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages

Answer (score 31):

### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Caramdir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/9561#9561) and [Jake's addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/9562#9562) to 
 **[Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/2975)**

#### Brief Description:

Allows the drawing of TikZ code over an included image.

[image]

#### Possible improvements:

- Adding some options to adjust the grid and the labels (maybe in combination with [my other suggestion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers/1223#1223)). Including a global option to switch off all grids.
- Could also be done as PGF-only variant

#### Improved code

I (Caramdir) encapsulated the idea into environments: https://gist.github.com/899107. Currently there is no option for grids, as Martin's grid code has no option to change the step size of the grid (a grid with lines at all integers is not very useful in this setting).

Comment: It may be useful to add some key-value driven interface for common highlighting features. See the [simpleslides](http://dl.contextgarden.net/modules/t-simpleslides/doc/context/third/simpleslides/simpleslides.pdf) module (page 29-35) for some examples.

Answer (score 22):

**TikZ/PGF Answer**

There are a variety of ways to use TikZ to add annotations to regular tables using the `[remember picture]` method.  Here are some:

[Highlighting table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells/4861#4861)

[How to draw lines around multiple table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-draw-lines-around-multiple-table-cells/9448#9448)

[How to format table with long column head entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12979/how-to-format-table-with-long-column-head-entries/12989#12989)

**Brief Description**

We tend to think of TiKZ as a method for making drawings, but it also can be used effectively to add annotations to regular LaTeX environments.  One especially useful use of it is to add annotations to tables, such as arrows pointing to cells or geometric shapes around cells.

[image: Highlighting table cells]

[image: How to draw lines around multiple table cells]

[image: How to format table with long column head entries]

Comment: I think this and the `tikzmark` trick in the solution about adding braces to text share a lot of features, maybe we should merge these answers?

Comment: [I am referring to this one](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers/1225#1225)

Comment: @Seamus That's not a bad idea. Shall I do that?  Others' comments?

Comment: I think that the answer I linked to doesn't have much to it apart from using the `[remember picture]` thing to add stuff. So maybe add those answers to this question and then we can delete the other one?

Answer (score 20):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Stroke with variable thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/trait-with-variable-thickness/14295#14295)

#### Brief Description:

Making variable width lines.

[image: variable width line]

#### Possible Improvements:

Connecting this with the [Changing colour halfway along path](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers/1224#1224)

Answer (score 20):

#### Tikz/PGF Answer:

[How to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-larg/25433#25433)

#### Brief Description

A method for magnifying rectangular sections of an image, displaying rectangles on top of the image to show which portions are magnified, and arranging the magnified portions in an aesthetically pleasing manner as a `subcaptionbox`.

Options for displaying a grid over the original image to ease placing the magnifications, using coloured frames to link the magnified portions to their position on the original image, or using different black and white dash patterns for better visibility in grayscale printouts.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements

- Support `subfig` in addition to `subcaption`, or optionally don't use subfigures at all.
- Add more/better dash patterns
- Use the approach in [Is there the easiest way to toggle (show/hide) navigational grids in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/is-there-the-easiest-way-to-toggle-show-hide-navigational-grids-in-tikz/14230#14230) to draw the grids

Answer (score 19):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex)

#### Brief Description:

Easily drawing draw masses, springs, dampers and grounds.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**TikZ/PGF Answer:**

[Changing the colour of a path half way along](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along/11003#11003)

**Brief description**

Changes the colour of a path halfway along. Useful for very thick lines so that the colour changes at the bend in a consistent way.

[image: split colour paths]

**Possible improvements**

Needs turning into a macro and needs stress-testing. It works by clipping, so we need to make sure that it doesn't do weird things for tight angles, more complex paths and the like.

**Status**

Switched to the *arrowhead* version.

- Code: Implemented
- Files: `tikzcolourpath.tex`
- Testing: None
- Documentation: None

Answer (score 15):

#### Tikz/PGF Answer:

[Need help creating a 3D cube from a 2D set of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz/29882#29882)

#### Brief Description

Macro for drawing cuboids with grids, with options for rotating and shading.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Chinese checkers board using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32302/chinese-checkers-board-using-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Draws a Chinese checkers board. Indicates moves.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements:

Include board designs for other similar games.

Answer (score 15):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Sieve of Eratosthenes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Showing how to find prime numbers by successively eliminating multiples.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Is there the easiest way to toggle (show/hide) navigational grids in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/is-there-the-easiest-way-to-toggle-show-hide-navigational-grids-in-tikz/14230#14230)

#### Brief Description:

Creates a `show grid=<options>` key which draws a grid with configurable labels:

[image]

This is quite useful in the creation phase of the picture.

#### Possible Improvements:

Could be converted to PGF-only code to make it also usable for `pgfpictures`.
Add an option to modify the distance between the lines.

Answer (score 14):

**TikZ/PGF Answer:**

OK this isn't so much one answer as a bunch of answers on these questions about braces:

- [Large braces over several items in an itemize with text by the brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12391/215)
- [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1559/215)

**Brief description**

The actual functionality could be "arbitrary braces" or just macro-ifying Andrew's tikzmark thing. (Which might be useful more generally).

[image: Large braces over several items in an itemize with text by the brace]

[image: Adding a large brace next to a body of text]

Comment: The `\tikzmark` macro is now in [tikzutils.sty](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzutils.sty).

Answer (score 14):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex)

#### Brief Description:

Highlighting text as if it were done with a text marker.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

#### Tikz/PGF Answer:

[How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz/12033#12033)

#### Brief Description

A method whereby one can specify the *inverse* of the usual clipping method.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-is-consume-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514)
as well as
[Stretching a framebox over the whole page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/stretching-a-framebox-over-the-whole-page/12128#12128)

#### Brief Description:

Provides a special `text area` node which allows the drawing/placing of elements on the page.

[image]

#### Possible improvements:

Some macros and/or environments based on this could be added, e.g. one which allows the inclusion of a box/image which fills the rest of the page. More specialized ones which generate a non-floating `figure` and `table` or custom (now pseudo-)float environment.

Also some special nodes for the header, footer and marginpar should be added. This would allow to easily draw material into this areas.

These solutions use TikZ/PGF but actually don't draw nothing.

Answer (score 12):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Tikz triangle with point colours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14613/tikz-triangle-with-point-colours/14630#14630)

#### Brief Description:

Three different solutions to drawing an “RGB triangle”. Each has its own advantages/disadvantages, so I'd add all three of them.

[image: rgb triangle]

#### Possible Improvements:

Make the solutions accept arbitrary color.

Answer (score 12):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How to make nice braids diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-make-efficiently-nice-braids-diagrams/16918#16918)

#### Brief Description:

Draw braid diagrams based on just specifying the crossings, as was done in a Metapost module by Stijn Symens.

Andrew's package shows off some PGF techniques quite nicely, so the source is well worth reading.

[image]

#### Blog post

[The Braids Package](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-braids-package/)

#### Requested features, implemented:

Matsaya suggested some features beyond those in Andrew's original implementation, each of which has been implemented:

1. *the possibility to draw horizontal braids* – the braid options allow PGF transformations on the output;
2. *the possibilities to draw the "floors"* – the new vertical bar syntax allows this;
3. *possibilities to have 2 (or more) nodes on the same floor (not really necessary)*  – the new syntax is to connect them with hyphens;
4. *to color a group of floor* – PGF styling options can now be passed for floors, both individually and collectively;
5. *individually choose the decoration (color, etc) of each "string"* – Likewise for strands;
6. *possibility to label the top or bottom of string (individually)* – Strands are labelled according to their positions, both at top and bottom.

Additionally, Charles noted that the original syntax for expressing crossings was not as compact as Stijn Symens' Metapost package.  Andrew implemented a new syntax of the form `s_1 s_2^{-1} s_3`, where the `s` isn't significant and can be anything that isn't "special".

#### Status

- Code: Implemented
- Tests: None
- Files: `braids.dtx`, `braids_test.tex`
- Documentation: Written

Comment: Just to note that the latest version of the braids "package" already implements many of these improvements.

Comment: @Andrew: Great.  Please edit.  BTW, did you know that answering my "challenge" and being 2nd to get the tikz-pgf tag badge officially makes you a PGF guru?

Comment: Edited as requested.  I'll have to make a "PGF Guru" sign for my office door.

Comment: Phew.  That was the hardest one yet.  Had to add 14 characters to the code.  Right, that's the lot on this one ... so far!

Answer (score 11):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How to draw triangular grid in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-to-draw-triangular-grid-in-tikz/1956#1956)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing a grid of triangles. Not very impressive but potentially useful and strangely absent from TikZ.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements:

Non-equilateral triangles. Hexagonal grid.

Answer (score 11):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Can I have framed blocks in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/can-i-have-framed-blocks-in-beamer/11481#11481)

#### Brief Description:

Have beamer `block` environments appear framed, rather than filled with a background colour.

OK, so it's not really TikZ, but it does involve some low level PGF hacking and it's a nice addition to beamer.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements:

Non-rounded version, thicker lines...

Comment: tcolorbox is surely a good fit for this

Answer (score 10):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Multiple equation numbers for a tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14599/multiple-equation-numbers-for-a-tikz-picture/14614#14614)

#### Brief Description:

Using TikZ is often a useful way of getting the pieces right in a complicated mathematical diagram.  If there's only one diagram, it's easy to label it by putting it in a suitable mathematics environment (`equation`, for example).  But if there are several diagrams, and it's not desirable to split them up (mutual alignment, for example), then it would be useful to be able to label the pieces individually.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements:

- Shift the actual placement of the equation numbers in to a `execute at end of picture` routine to ensure that the bounding box used is the actual bounding box of the picture (and not a half-way stage).
- Allow for customisation as to labels on the left and right.
- Allow for customisation of label style (parentheses and so forth).

#### Status:

- Code: Implemented
- Files: `tikzeqnos.tex`
- Testing: None
- Documentation: None

Comment: This is similar to what Joseph Wright's [chemscheme](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/chemscheme.html) does, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

#### Tikz/PGF Answer:

[How can I set the background color of the rows and columns of a matrix node in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-of-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-matrix-node-in-ti/14092#14092)

#### Brief Description

After setting up a matrix using TikZ, this puts nodes in each cell of the right size so that they tile the matrix.  This can be used to, for example, colour the matrix with no gaps between the cells.

[image]

#### Status

- Code: Implemented
- Tests: None
- Files: `matrixcells.dtx`, `matrixcells_test.tex`
- Documentation: Written

Answer (score 9):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Drawing a circle on a non xy-plane with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/drawing-a-circle-on-a-non-xy-plane-with-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing perspectively correct circles on non-xy planes without worrying about the actual transformation.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Applying a postaction to every path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Solves the problem of postactions being recursively applied in a scope. Very short code, but can be rather handy.

Comment: This is now in [tikzutils.sty](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzutils.sty).

Comment: The link is broken. The correct one is now http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzutils.dtx

Answer (score 8):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Add more anchors to standard TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/add-more-anchors-to-standard-tikz-nodes/14772#14772)

#### Brief Description:

Adds anchors like `north north east` or `west south west` to the TikZ rectangle shape to augment the standard nodes.

#### Possible Improvements:

Do the same for the `circle` shape.

#### Status

- Code: Implemented for the `rectangle` shape.
- Tests: None
- Files: `pgflibraryshapes.tex-sx.dtx`
- Documentation: Partially written

Answer (score 7):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Drawing a tree of grids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/drawing-a-tree-of-grids/14849#14849)

#### Brief Description:

Adds a rectangular node with a grid inside and some additional anchors.

[image]

#### Status

- Code: Implemented
- Tests: None
- Files: `pgflibraryshapes.tex-sx.dtx`
- Documentation: None

Comment: This definitely needs to go in. I'd like to see `mid` and `base` anchors for the grid cells as well, but I haven't been able to add them myself (I find all those `\noexpands` really intimidating...)

Comment: @Jake: Yes the `\noexpand`s are annoying. Since there are no text nodes at the moment, I don't really know where to put `mid` and `base`. It might be useful to rewrite this as a multipart node.

Comment: This is now in [pgflibraryshapes.tex-sx](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pgflibraryshapes.tex-sx.dtx) (without `mid` and `base`)

Answer (score 7):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Mexican hat in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14818)

#### Brief Description:

Draws a mexican hat.

[image]

#### Possible Improvements:

The lower part of the brim can be improved.

Comment: I don't think this is the sort of thing that needs doing often enough that it needs putting in a package.

Comment: I'm going to give this a +1 because it is a neat example of the `arc` and `sin` path construction methods which I have never really paid attention to before.

Answer (score 7):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Putting a timeline for dates in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/putting-a-timeline-for-dates-in-moderncv)

#### Brief Description:

Adding progressbar-like timelines to your CV. Available as a package: [moderntimeline](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Modify TikZ coil decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/modify-tikz-coil-decoration/43605#43605)

#### Brief Description:

Separates the coil decoration in two - one that goes up and an other that goes down. This can be used to draw coils that wraps around e.g a cylinder.

[image: coil wrap]

#### Possible Improvements:

I think that TikZ would benefit from a highlevel way to modify existing decorations.

Answer (score 7):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47394/86

The shape is finished by [Altermundus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/altermundus) and [zeroth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7049/zeroth) in the following answer :

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47484/3235

#### Brief Description:

Draw a Batman logo in TikZ.

#### Possible Improvements:

1. Make it into a node shape, with customisable colours, text inset into the bat, and anchors galore.
2. Add logos of other superheros (bonus points for bananaman, supergran, and supertex)

Comment: Adding shiny glass-like effect may be interesting, see the example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47273/9467

Comment: For the interested, it is still under construction to make it an explicit `.sty` file with additional goodies.

Answer (score 6):

#### Brief Description:

[How can we display fireworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39485/how-can-we-display-fireworks)

#### Possible Improvements:

Drawing fireworks explosions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How can I draw a cake using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-can-i-draw-a-cake-using-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Proof that you can do everything with TikZ, even the invitations for the birthday party of your children.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Surface of Revolution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/surface-of-revolution)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing the surface created by rotating a curve around an axis.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[TikZ - multi-color double circle node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36856/tikz-multi-color-double-circle-node)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing nodes with a double circular border, connectable by both circles.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Spirograph, Continuous Rotations in TikZ or PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/spirograph-continuous-rotations-in-tikz-or-pstricks)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing rotatinally symmetric objects.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Drawing simple 3D cylinders in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing cylinders correctly, independant of the orientation of the coordinate axes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Topological Quantum Field Theory diagrams with pstricks or tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/topological-quantum-field-theory-diagrams-with-pstricks-or-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing diagrams about topological quantum field theory.

[image]

Comment: This one has actually already been done (not sure if you're aware of that) - and while I'm commenting, are you on some sort of mission, here!  I just got 15 notifications in my SE inbox.

Comment: Caffeine is not a drug! No, it's not! NOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[Triangular numbers in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37707/triangular-numbers-in-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing a number of spheres perfectly aligned in a triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How to change the line width of the lines connecting spies and the spied region](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/how-to-change-the-line-width-of-the-lines-connecting-spies-and-the-spied-region)

#### Brief Description:

influencing both the line conncting the spy and the spied region, as well as the border of the spied region.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### TikZ/PGF Answer:

[How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz)

#### Brief Description:

Drawing a decorated christmas tree.

[image]

[image]