# Tex.SX package development

Tags: discussion, chat, tex-sx-package

I have noticed that there is an effort to build [packages from answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/from-answers-to-packages).

I would like to do something like that, however I am a noviece, therefore I am looking for someone to assist in the creation. This type of request does not quite fit the Q&A format of the site, however it is THE (only) tex community I have been using excessively. The [launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/tex-sx) does not seem to have a forum and besides that I doubt that it is half as active as here. Also I am not quite sure about how to use chatrooms properly (and invite people to them).

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: See [How to invite someone to chat?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3591/5764)...

Comment: Note that Launchpad is not the most used of the DVCS sites: of the projects listed in the answers to packages threads for A-M/N-Z, there are 36 listed for Bitbucket, 23 for Github, and only 5 for Launchpad.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I am unfailiar with the term DVCS? Also I think we talk about to different thinks, While I am not sure what question you refer to I think you refer to a list (maybe [this one](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2484/19326)?) of packages *maintained* by people that are part of this community, while I refer to the effort to collaborate on packages *inspired* by questions in this community.

Comment: @ted: DVCS stands for Distributed Version Control System.  The reason I think these numbers are relevant is that they may give an idea of where the activity is and who might look at which page.  I haven't made any suggestion about how to get your idea off the ground, but maybe having it in the context of a wider mentoring program would work best.

Comment: @CharlesStewart  "wider mentoring program" was something I was thinking of, if there is something like this for (la)tex. Do you happen to have any pointers?