# Would like to find people for developing project – appropriate?

Tags: discussion, community

I have this need for a biblatex package for legislation and other legal documents (for reference: [What is the proper way to cite a legal document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cite-a-legal-document) and many other questions) and I was thinking of gathering some people, if there are any, that might be able to help. I do not have enough skills myself to realize the project (barely getting my head around [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) ), but would like to cooperate with someone.

Is a question on tex.stackexchange.com appropriate for finding people, or should I go about it some other way?

Comment: kind of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135295/how-can-i-make-some-money-out-of-my-tex-skills

Comment: I am trying to achieve similar goals and would be happy to cooperate with you or share resources (though I am not how much our legal systems have in common). Having BibLaTeX styles for many jurisdictions would be a must for every lawyer out there. I would suggest you ask on the `comp.text.tex` newsgroup (available on Google groups). If you want, you can also contact me (my pseudonym – gmail).

Comment: But to answer your question: there are very few of us at the moment, even worldwide, and chances are we need to build a lawyer's mailing list / group for ourselves if we want anything to work out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is clear: To post a question on the main site, it has to be neither: off-topic (for instance it can't be a feature request), opinion-based (so no questions like "I have an idea ... What do you think about it?") nor unclear what you are asking (i.e., it has to be a true question).

If you look for gathering people for a project, you may try posting a question on meta. Many sites would think that this is inappropriate, but TeX.SX seems to gather a lot of TeX developers and discussion on developments are not uncommon here (especially in our chat).

Altogether, certainly nobody is going to be angry or offended if you give it a try here.

Answer (score 9):

If it's the kind of project that might generate good Q&A on the main site, or might lead to the kind of packages beloved of "From Answers to packages", I'd definitely count it as on-topic here on Meta.  It's not asking for the right sort of thing to be a good Stack Exchange main-site question, I think.

Answer (score 9):

An important detail is that if you don't have anything but looking for someone who has the skillz then they might not need you to start with anyway. Hence making a good business case is also something that might trigger some activity.

For that reason, you might want to make a really good question such that people jump on the wagon and as Charles Stewart mentioned do the hard work themselves just for the fun of it. We have many `this question led to a package` cases on the site.

[From Answers to Packages](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/from-answers-to-packages)

and many examples of package-creating questions

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q="This+question+led+to"