# Birthday Celebrations

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It's not that long to our first birthday (July 26th), and it would be nice to mark it in some way.

I'm sure that there will be plenty of silly ideas - save them for *chat*.  Let's have serious ideas here.

Comment: Is the birthday on the 26th (start of the private beta), or one week later (start of the public beta)? Or when the final site was launched?

Comment: @Caramdir: I didn't consider that, but given that we're having the discussion _now_, I think putting it off to the official launch is too long.  I'd go for the start of _public_ beta.

Answer (score 13):

I think we should make an effort to bring down the number of unanswered questions before our birthday. There's plenty of questions where answers haven't been upvoted and the OP hasn't returned since asking to accept the answer. But I'm sure lurking in that list are some questions that we can find answers to!

Also, if there are questions with answers on the list, and the answers are good, please *do* upvote them: that way, they're off the "unanswered" list...

Comment: Sounds like a Necromancer-Fest as a birthday party? Great idea `:-)`. As for not-accepted answers, is it correct that nobody but the OP can accept an answer? That'd mean if they haven't returned and won't do so, there's no way for these questions to get out of limbo.

Comment: @doncherry: True, but if the answer gets an upvote or two (don't remember exactly how many, but it's either 1 or 2) then it gets taken off the "unanswered" list so as far as the rest of us are concerned, it's the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew: One upvote is sufficient.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks.  I keep forgetting how many it is ...

Comment: @Jasper: I suppose the question will re-enter the "unanswered" list. Haven't tested it, though.

Comment: What about generally reducing the number of answers (and questions) with zero score? Apparently "beginner questions" and their answers have a tendency to be neither up- nor down-voted. The same holds for "late" answers to older questions that already have an accepted answer, but to which the additional answer provides nevertheless additional value. The problem with "zero score" contributions is that their value is basically "undecided", which doesn't suit the community too well and may put off beginners from trying them. IMHO every contribution should get an either positive or negative score.

Answer (score 10):

One that springs to mind is to get the first version of the TeX-SX-package up on CTAN.

#### References:

- [What are your favourite TikZ/PGF answers?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers)
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages

Comment: I've applied to be part of the project at Launchpad. Could you approve the application?

Comment: Ah, that was you!  There was no information in the email that I got which linked the user to someone on this site so I was going to post a question here asking who it was.  You've just saved me the bother.  I'll approve it when I can remember how to do that ...

Comment: Done (easier than I thought).  And when I went to the launchpad page itself then I saw that the "mystery user" was "Jake".  Odd that the email I got didn't say that.

Comment: Cheers! I changed my username after applying for membership in the group - the old one was "tentotwo", because that's when the hands on a clock look like a smile - which might have confused you. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

Martin suggests we schedule a 'party' in Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1340323#1340323. Seems like an interesting idea :-)

Comment: I bring the drinks!

Answer (score 4):

We could start the TeX.SX blog on the 1st birthday, July 26th.

- [How about a TeX.SX blog?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-about-a-tex-sx-blog)
- [What would you like to read in a TeX.SX blog?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/what-would-you-like-to-read-in-a-tex-sx-blog)

Answer (score 4):

We also could have a special community ad on that day. Maybe showing a cake with one candle and saying "Happy Birthday TeX.SX" or something. It could link to some birthday announcement of meta or the birthday chat room when it is running.

Comment: [My attempt on an ad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ggDbC.png). Can I haz cake? `=)`