# TeX.SX T-Shirts

Tags: discussion, community, sponsorship, site-promotion

The idea of TeX.SX T-shirts came recently up in the chat. Would there be any interest from people to buy one? The idea is that we designed it ourselves and have it produces.

I just had a quick look and found an online shop which allows people to upload and sell their own T-shirts (and pullovers, etc.). When the commission you could get is set to 0 a basic printed T-shirt is around 18-20 Euro inkl. shipping (varies from country, shipped from Germany; this was based on a relative simple shirt ca. 14 Euro + 4 Euro shipping around Germany). This is nice because others websites make you buy dozens at once and then one of us would have to ship it to everyone else. This makes it also relative risk-free because we don't have any minimum number to order and uploading it is free.

The question of **copyright** came also up. Could the official stackexchange staff, which also reads this meta, please give us an idea if using the `{TeX}` logo and the `tex.stackexchange.com` URL would be any issue. I personally guess not. It's basically free advertising for them as well. We can of course use some other place as well if we find a better one (shipping to USA is for example already at 9 dollar).

Paulo Cereda already made an example T-shirt, so I include it as an eye catcher:

[image: Example T-shirt]

I would be happy about any feedback.

Comment: Hye, I'd buy one. I live off corporate T-shits!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have already started designing T-Shirts and Stickers for some of the SE2.0 communities.

For example: [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users), [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/english-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) etc. I'll try to finish up the swag design for all of our graduated communities this month.

We'll send out a free swag package to the [top users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)(first 2 pages, sorted by rep). We will also have the T-shirts and stickers available in our [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) later too, for those who are interested in purchasing them.

Comment: This is GREAT! I had a look at the shop and I love your other products, like the Stein (funny name by the way: it means "stone" in German, which was the original material for it, but now it is made from glass and isn't called like that in Germany). It's a pity that shipping to Europe is quite expensive (especially for the fragile Stein).

Comment: @Martin I like them too! For the initial "package" we're thinking about doing t-shirts and stickers only. As for the design, what I had in mind for the TeX.se community is very similar to the one in your mockup. I was thinking using the site's header and the url below it.

Comment: The mockup was done by Paulo Cereda which also planned to make a final design, if I understood him correctly.

Comment: @Jin: Great news! The mockup I did was just to raise our hopes to have a cool T-shirt. `=P` Could we have some custom text in the design? (I put both `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter` in my mockup as they are LaTeX commands and have a semantic meaning in the T-shirt - front and back - probably a geeky joke). `=P` Anyway, if you need help, and if I can help, just let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the T-Shirt in action. The Photo has been made at the TeX User Group Conference 2011 in India.

[image]

This photo is part of the [32nd Annual Meeting of TUG Album](http://download.river-valley.com/tug2011/album/index.html).

Comment: Nice! One thing I was wondering about is: should the "{TeX}" logo not be bigger?

Answer (score 7):

The T-Shirts might be sponsored by StackExchange. I added the tag [sponsorship](/questions/tagged/sponsorship) to make it visible.

Robert Cartaino wrote in [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/):

> Any community that shows sufficient
>   effort and innovative ideas to promote
>   their site will be offered a budget
>   and resources to make those ideas
>   happen. Think of it as matching funds
>   — except we’re matching effort,
>   innovation, resources, and ideas from
>   the community.
>
> ...
>
> We can provide access to professional
>   designers and design give-aways like
>   t-shirts or bumper stickers for
>   interesting contests and events.

This also solves the copyright issue.

Comment: This sounds great! In this case it would be cheaper and easier to order batch. Then however we have the issue of dispatching it to everyone.