# Do we want Stack Exchange to become an institutional member of the TUG?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sponsorship, tug

I suggest Stack Exchange Inc. becomes an [institutional member of the TeX User Group](http://tug.org/instmem.html).

I'm glad that many votes alread show interest in this topic. So let's work it out!

- What are the benefits for our site, for SE and for the TeX community?
- What is required?
- How does it work?

Feel free to add answers and also to edit community wiki answers. Especially contributions of TUG members would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea. I'm already a  regular member of TUG and UK-TUG...

Comment: I'm glad to see upvotes supporting the idea. I will write an email to Stack Exchange Inc. drawing attention to this topic.

Comment: i support this, though obviously i'm biased.  if the idea is accepted, please note that the issue of tugboat now in process is expected to be sent to the printer by the end of july, so the current institutional members list will close by about july 25.  regarding individual memberships, they're usually expected to be at the same address.  contact robin (office@tug.org) to discuss this since it's a rather unusual arrangement; i'm sure that at least the moderators would be acceptable, since they have an "official" connection.

Comment: We are moving forward on this from our end.  I will let you know when it goes through.  I smell a blog post? (:

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Benefits for the TeX Stack Exchange site

- As institutional member, Stack Exchange Inc. could name eight TeX.SX members to get individual membership each. Each of those site members will:

  - Get access to the journal [TUGboat](http://tug.org/TUGboat/), The Communications of the TeX Users Group. So they can be up to date with most recent developments in the TeX community, bringing that knowledge back to our SE site.
  - Receive the [TeX Collection software](http://tug.org/texcollection/), which is an extensive ready-to-run TeX system for most Unix variants, Mac OS X, and Windows. Having that, they can support questioners regarding problems with the most modern software.
  - Get discounted conference fees. So we can expect that more TeX SE site users go to conferences and talk about TeX.SE: on conferences we can attract experts for our SE site.

  There are even further [TUG benefits](http://tug.org/aims_ben.html), such as access to the [TUG member area](https://www.tug.org/members/) and to TUG books online. Each of those, which firstly are of use to the TeX SE member, will bring profit to the site in the long run.
- Stack Exchange will be named and listed as [institutional TUG member](http://tug.org/instmem.html) in each issue of [TUGboat](http://tug.org/TUGboat/). So each issue of the journal will contain promotion for our site. Again, we are visible for the experts.

### Benefits for Stack Exchange

- It will be a great story, and nice stuff for a press release. Blogs will spread the word!
- It will officially connect Stack Exchange to community organizations such as [TUG](http://tug.org) and other [TeX user associations around the world](http://tug.org/usergroups.html).

### Benefits for the TeX community

- The existence and growth of the Stack Exchange TeX site is already a benefit. By joining as a member it helps directly supporting and promoting the use of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related systems worldwide and sponsors the development of TeX projects such as TeX Live.

### What are the costs?

The institutional rate is $500. This can even be tax deductible. Compare it to the benefits above.

### How does it work?

- SE may join online by submitting an [online form](https://www.tug.org/forms/2011/memberapp.html)
- or by [contacting the TUG office](http://tug.org/contact.html)
- or just mailing to office@tug.org
- Information is here: [TUG Membership Information](http://tug.org/join.html)

For sure TUG will gladly provide information as soon as the contact has been established.