# Sponsored TUG membership

Tags: discussion, sponsorship, tug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TUG Membership: Names for 2013](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/tug-membership-names-for-2013)

[Last year StackExchange became a member of TUG](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/do-we-want-stack-exchange-to-become-an-institutional-member-of-the-tug). With that come eight individual memberships, that [were given out to some members of the community](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/who-would-like-to-become-a-member-of-the-tex-user-group-sponsored-by-stack-exch). I was one of the lucky eight chosen and enjoyed my TUG membership for the last year.

However, I haven't been very active on TeX.SX lately, so I feel that there are other members of the community who deserve that membership more than I do and could use it better to improve TeX.SX as a whole. I don't know when the individual memberships can be changed, but I would guess that the new year is a good time.

Thus — assuming that StackExchange will continue to be a TUG member in 2013 — who wants to have my individual membership?

Comment: Does that individual membership come with an individual TUGboat subscription?

Comment: @MartinSchröder -- all individual tug memberships come with an individual tugboat subscription; the real question is, is that a paper or an electronic subscription?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: _You_ of all people should know that, being a board member _and_ editor of TUGboat `:-)`. The [membership page on tug.org](http://www.tug.org/join.html) is not clear on this, but since group members get only one physical copy, I assume that institutional members also get only one physical copy.

Comment: @MartinSchröder -- actually, i don't know what was chosen for the tex.sx membership.  the math society is an institutional member, and each designated individual member gets a paper copy. it has nothing to do with me being a board member or editor of tugboat.  the institution (or maybe each of its individuals) can make a decision, and only the institution, its designated individuals, and the tug office know what that is.  (but i will ask at the tug office for this case.)

Comment: i have checked whether a paper copy of tugboat is included with this tug membership.  yes, it is, according to the tug office.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I got paper copies delivered by mail.

Comment: We should check with StackOverflow what they would like to do.  Assuming that they will continue their TUG subscription, maybe they'd like to rotate the individual memberships.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I am one of the sponsored members and I think that rotating every year or perhaps every two years is a good idea.