# TUG Membership: Names for 2014

Tags: discussion, sponsorship, tug

StackExchange [continues to support TUG with corporate membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/should-we-keep-our-tex-user-group-membership) (many thanks). With that come eight individual memberships that can be given out to members of the community. The time has come to select our representatives for 2014. For reference, Eight top voted members during last year [TUG Membership: Names for 2013](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2906/15717) who have enjoyed [TUG membership benefits](http://tug.org/aims_ben.html)

Following the model from previous years, I'd like to ask people to put themselves forward.  There are no restrictions on standing other than having to be a member of the TeX StackExchange site: in particular, the existing 'representatives' are very welcome to put their names forward to continue. [Note: I've called the people we put forward 'representatives', but that's mainly because I can't think of a better term. Nominees should not feel the need to represent TeX-sx other than being members of the site and therefore interested in TeX in some way!]

The model for selection of representatives is as follows. We will have a two stage process, first 'nomination' then 'election'. The first phase runs for five days, until 1700 GMT on 2014-01-07.  Each person who wishes to be considered should post an answer, where they can (if they wish) say what makes them a good choice. They should then immediately delete their answer.

The second phase will then begin. All of the answers will be undeleted, and everyone should take a look at these answers and vote for deserving candidates: remember there are eight places available! Again, there will be five days to vote, ending 1700 GMT on 2014-01-12. At that stage, the top eight names will be forwarded to the StackExchange community staff for notification to TUG.

In the event of a tie in number of votes, the mod team will decide which of the tied members are put forward to StackExchange. The mod team may also include additional names *if* at the end of the voting process there are fewer than eight nominees with positive scores.

---

At the end of the voting period, the tallies were as follows:

- [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar), 25
- [Sean Allred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423/sean-allred), 20
- [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), 18
- [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder), 18
- [azetina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10898/azetina), 17
- [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t), 17
- [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke), 17
- [morbusg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1410/morbusg), 17
- [Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/fran), 16
- [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz), 13

Our representatives for 2014 are therefore Harish Kumar, Sean Allred, Ulrike Fischer, cgnieder, azetina, Torbjørn T., Henri Menke, and morbusg. Congratulations!

Comment: Awesome! I won't renew mine, it's time to give others the same opportunity I had. `:)`

Comment: I won't participate in the elections either. I've got an individual membership and I've already renewed it ;)

Comment: I also won't participate. I've benefited from the past two years, so it's time for someone else to get a chance.

Comment: I won't renew this time either. I greatly appreciate the opportunity for last time, but I think that in the next year I'll have little time to devote to TeX, so it is better for others to have the opportunity.

Comment: **Just a remark: If anyone considers a candidature, but has a feeling of not being "too strong", they should just give it a try and post one. The 8 memberships we are allowed should be taken as 8 opportunities for people to get more involved in the wider TeX community :)**

Comment: as editor of tugboat, and a founding member of tug, i encourage enthusiastic users of (la)tex who wish to know more to take a look at past issues of [tugboat](http://www.tug.org/tugboat/) (issues published within the last 12 months are accessible only to members, but the contents list is open to all), and if you like what you see, submit your name.

Comment: The election phase has started: please vote! New nominations may still be submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. Am more than happy... dont know what else to say. YESSSS!! When do we get notified about the renewal?

Answer (score 28):

*If* and *only if*,   there are free slots, and if nobody notices my nomination in other way, I would like to put my name just to have a taste of TUG membership. Though I have been in TeX world for long time, I was never a member (I just didn't think of it). If I like it I will go for an individual membership after this.

I have no specific goals/aims regarding what I do with the membership, hence feel free to downvote. :-)

Comment: I may not be a good choice after all :-)

Comment: It would seem that the community has *other* plans for you and TUG :-)

Comment: I am grateful to all my friends here. You have been very nice to me. My heart felt thanks to you all.

Answer (score 21):

At Alan's heartwarming insistence, I'd like to nominate myself if there are free slots.

It seems everyone else has given a little tidbit about why, so here goes:
I've almost exploded in my interest of TeX and TeX systems,
  and I would be excited to see what other people are talking about and doing.
I'm not privy to the full benefits of a TUG membership, but I would be excited and frankly honored to find out about it personally.

Comment: I asked Sean to nominate himself because I think he has shown super enthusiasm for learning TeX, and has been a great addition to the site both in terms of his questions and his answers.

Answer (score 19):

I humbly put myself on the list. I already am a member of [dante](http://www.dante.de/) and would like get the opportunity to help me decide if I pay for a joint membership in the future. (I've been tempted for a while now...)

If I get the chance I promise to write the article about chemistry and LaTeX for TUGboat Karl Berry asked me for about two years ago... (I'll probably be using my yet unfinished [series of blog posts](http://texwelt.de/blog/tag/chemie/) on TeXwelt.de as a basis.)

Comment: i see a tugboat article on `xtemplate`, but nothing yet on chemistry.  consider yourself nagged!  (grin)

Comment: @barbara I know. I have finished it in German and it appeared in Dante's DTK but I still need to translate it. I haven't forgotten...

Answer (score 19):

If there are free slots I'm putting my name on the list with the same reason as cgnieder: I'm already member of dante and I would like get the opportunity to help me decide if I pay for a joint membership in the future. But I can't promise an article or something like this as I haven't currently the time to write it.

Comment: Only if you come to Dante50. :-)

Comment: @martinschr: I plan too come but don't know yet if and for how many dsys I can manage it.

Answer (score 19):

TeX.SX and TUGboat have been invaluable resources for me. To be honest, I feel really welcomed here and even when I have asked several questions, I am glad, that at times, I am able to answer a few here and there. I am learning and similar to my last submission for selection, I am moving forward the TeX voice here in my country, Belize. Currently I am tutoring two of my students in LaTeX. One of the projects that I have initiated is writing a Mathematics book and so far, with all the resources from TUGboat and TeX.SX I have managed to achieve 2 chapters.

Therefore, I would gladly reapply for a TUGboat membership.

Comment: I would like to express my support for azetina. As he [explained last year](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2931), this is basically the only opportunity how he can get the membership, and since there're not many TeXers in Belize, his membership is valuable for propagating TeX around the world.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tohecz. Indeed I am trying my best in all possible ways even trying to implement it at the institution I work, teaching some of my colleagues as well. Hopefully it will be possible for to continue my growth with the invaluable resources provided by TeX.SX and TUGboat.

Answer (score 18):

I'd like to join the election for a TUG membership.

- I hope I can stand a chance against the other, more trusted applicants. I'm a user for 1 year and 11 months now, but really started using this site about 1 year ago. My favourite tags are [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) and [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks).
- In the past, I read interesting TUGboat articles online, when they were available. I also read Die TeXnische Komödie as I am a member of dante.
- I advertise for TeX and TeX.SX in university.
- Currently I'm reading the TeXbook to become a better user and I believe, that a TUG membership will help me improving my skills.
- Hopefully, one day I can also publish in the TUGboat or in dante's Die TeXnische Komödie.

Answer (score 18):

I'll, uh, hereby nominate myself. I'm not sure what's expected of the representatives, but I'll cope in case I'm lucky. I haven't done so much answering / editing / voting / reviewing last year because of being so busy busy busy, but hopefully I'll have more time this year.

I'll let you in on a little secret about me: My favorite past time is taking a random article from arXiv and re-TeXing it with plain XeTeX/LuaTeX. I haven't got the faintest clue what most of them are talking about, but I find it somehow relaxing – therapeutic, even.

Weird? Maybe. Fun? Definitely! Weird? Hey, you asked that already!

Answer (score 17):

I am very far from the merits, reputation and experience of many members of this site. And my knowledge about LaTeX and TUG is still superficial. Thus, certainly I will not a good 'representant' of TeX-sx. My membership could be surely of little utility in TUG (even less than here, if this is possible).

After this "self-promotion", it only remains to add that as I am still curious and I love LaTeX, so anyway, I present my candidacy for membership of TUG, just in case there is a stroke of luck and all the places are not covered with better candidates.

Answer (score 16):

I don't really like nominating myself for anything, but I'll make an exception.

Not really sure what to say though. I'm a mere user, my contributions to the TeX world so far are mainly those on this site. I've been a TUG member for two years I think. My main reason for joining was to give a little bit back, and I'll renew my membership if I'm not 'awarded' one here. (For that reason I'll place myself last in line.)

Answer (score 15):

Since the list is not yet full (7 at the start of writing), I gladly reapply. My connection to TUG was for example

- [initiating our institutional membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/do-we-want-stack-exchange-to-become-an-institutional-member-of-the-tug),
- [visiting a TUG meeting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/going-to-a-conference-the-tug-2011-experience) and making a [TeX.SX related presentation](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/events/tex-online/) there,
- writing a [TeX.SX related article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102kottwitz.pdf) for the TUGboat from it.

That was fun, I wish the same fun for our fellow members, I already enjoyed 2 years. And if it happens that it might continue for me so I'd be happy.