# TUG Membership: Names for 2015

Tags: discussion, tug, sponsorship

StackExchange [continues to support TUG with corporate membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/annual-tex-user-group-membership-question-2015-edition) (many thanks). With that come eight individual memberships that can be given out to members of the community. The time has come to select our representatives for 2015. (See [TUG Membership: Names for 2014](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/tug-membership-names-for-2014) for last year's selection.)

I'd like to ask people to put themselves forward. There are no restrictions on standing other than having to be a member of the TeX StackExchange site: in particular, the existing 'representatives' are very welcome to put their names forward to continue. [Note: I've called the people we put forward 'representatives', but that's mainly because I can't think of a better term. Nominees should not feel the need to represent TeX-sx other than being members of the site and therefore interested in TeX in some way!]

The model for selection of representatives is as follows. We will have a two stage process, first 'nomination' then 'election'. The first phase runs for five days, until 2100 GMT on 2015-01-12. Each person who wishes to be considered should post an answer, where they can (if they wish) say what makes them a good choice. They should then immediately delete their answer. Please don't vote on any answers during this phase: any votes cast will be ignored.

In the second phase, all of the answers will be undeleted, and everyone should take a look at these answers and vote for deserving candidates: remember there are eight places available! Again, there will be five days to vote, ending 2100 GMT on 2015-01-17. At that stage, the top eight names will be forwarded to the StackExchange community staff for notification to TUG.

In the event of a tie in number of votes, the mod team will decide which of the tied members are put forward to StackExchange. The mod team may also include additional names if at the end of the voting process there are fewer than eight nominees with positive scores.

---

Everyone is welcome to vote for as many or as few candidates as they wish. Remember that there are a total of eight places available to be selected. New nominations can be added during the voting phase.

---

At the end of the voting period, the tallies were:

- [azetina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10898/azetina), 29
- [Jubobs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs), 29
- [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer), 28
- [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr), 28
- [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), 24
- [Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/963/yiannis-lazarides), 24
- [yo'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/yo), 20
- [Sean Allred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423/sean-allred), 19
- [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm), 19
- [LaRiFaRi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32245/larifari), 16
- [Ian Thompson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2417/ian-thompson), 15

while [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) withdrew from the selection process. The top seven names (azetina, Jubobs, Christian Hupfer, cfr, Werner,  Yiannis Lazarides and yo') are therefore automatically selected as our 'representatives' and will be forwarded to StackExchange. Thomas Sturm has indicated he is happy to allow Sean Allred to take the final place, and so his name will be forwarded with the seven others to the network to be passed to TUG.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Answers should be given to this question, then deleted as I say (that way we give everyone an equal chance in the voting phase).

Comment: Thanks for clearification, but in addition, I think the possibility to nominate other users here would be fine as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's a bit tricky as without the delete business voting might get skewed. Let's say you can nominate others but we need confirmation from the nominee that they are happy before voting starts: no point for example upvoting someone with TUG membership anyway. (I'll mod-ping any people nominated by others.)

Comment: I already have a personal TUG membership. :-)

Comment: It seems that I have to repeat my comment from the last year: 
 
**If anyone considers a candidature, but has a feeling of not being "too strong", they should just give it a try and post one. The 8 memberships we are allowed should be taken as 8 opportunities for people to get more involved in the wider TeX community :)**

Comment: I make it easy for you: The algorihm for the 8te place should be *first come, first serve*. So, I draw back my name in favour of Sean Allread who applied first. Congratulations, Sean :-)

Comment: Congs to all those elected.

Comment: @JosephWright and Stefan Kottwitz and StackExchange: **Thanks for organizing this! :)** Do you need our names and postal addresses?

Comment: @yo' We are passing names to StackExchange: I'm not quite sure how this is handled, but I guess either they or TUG will be in direct contact.

Comment: @JosephWright Pops has contacted us just now. Just to let you know.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I'm honored :) Thank you :')

Answer (score 28):

Well, I was kindly 'forced' by Paulo Cereda to put my name down here as well. I am not sure if I am the right person to obtain a TUG membership, being a TeX.SX member not for a long time right now, so please judge from my statements of 'what is' below.

I joined TeX.SX in June 2013 just for getting information on something I could not solve on my own and got thrilled by the great wisdom on all issues about TeX -- I thought I would know a lot of LaTeX since I use it for almost 20 years now, but this was an error: I learned more TeX internals within just about one year since I am a member of TeX.SX than in the preceding 16 years before. Thanks to the TeX.SX community.

I enjoy this community, do a lot of reviews, flags and answer or post questions and the most times funny chat of TeX.SX. My main contributions are answers on [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros), [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) and [counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters) and I have learned so much during this time that I wrote two packages and published them on CTAN/TeXlive in the meantime.

I am a member of DANTE already and considered to get a TUG membership as well and would feel honoured to be a member of the TUG community as well. Besides that, the TUG 2015 meeting will take place in Darmstadt, which is only about 200 km away from my place here in Germany ;-)

As can be found in my profile: I work as a teacher for Physics and Mathematics and use LaTeX exclusively for worksheets, presentations, examens and teacher home office organisation. And I try to persuade my colleagues to use LaTeX as well. In addition, I train young math/physics teachers and will provide courses in LaTeX in near future for them.

And I am the guy from which egreg 'steals' text parts to use in his answers ;-)

> **I will vote for the other nominees as well of course (and not for me, even if I could)**

Answer (score 28):

Let me start with an email I just recently sent to the TUG office. Here is how it goes.

> Dear Angel,
>
> On 01/05/2015 08:53 AM, Angel Zetina wrote:

```
My name is Angel Zetina, a current subscriber of TUG.
```

> Thank you kindly :)

```
I was wondering if the office at TUG could give me some insight as to how many Belizean
(country of Belize) subscribers there are. I would like to initiate a
basic campaign to invite more Belizeans to join TUG and provide for them
a seminar about TeX and its uses.
```

> There is exactly one TUG member in Belize (for all years), and that,
>   of course, is you. Wow. That's so surprising!

```
Note that I got my current subscription via tex.stackexchange.com as
contributing user.
```

> Indeed! So great! Thank you!
>
> I wish I had better news regarding TUG member numbers in Belize.
>   Certainly there are users. One obvious place to look would be
>   university math departments or elsewhere in the university where
>   students write technical papers. Let me know if I can help in any way.
>   Sincerely,
>
> Robin
>   TUG office

Well that was not a surprise for me but still it is sad as we have two major universities in my country; the University of Belize and Galen University. So far I have managed to help one of my colleagues to get interested in using LaTeX and by so doing trying to form a local TeX user group which I have called BTUG, short for Belize TeX User Group. My brother has joined in one of my colleagues has managed to publish a short story and workbook in LaTeX (independent of me helping which is great.)

On my corner, what have I achieved so far? Well, I managed to write the Students Handbook for my institution purely in LaTeX optimising the code day by day. By the way, I recently received the TUGBoat Vol 35 No. 1 and 2, 2014. Here are some snap shots of the handbook:

[image]
[image]

And of course, I am still working on that book of mine. Here are two snapshots:

[image]
[image]

Honestly, what I have achieved is a compilation of everyone's advice and motivation here in TX.SX and continuous reading and practice. An invaluable person to my success so far, can't remember who it is, :), but quote

> @azetina Admission to the guild of TeX wizards just costs work on the
>   TeXbook and exercise. ;-) –  egreg Jan 5 at 17:30

And that is so true.

All in all, with the current referal system that TUG has implemented I will do my best to send invitations to my colleagues and especially to the Universities in my country; we have a long way to go together. Thanks a lot for the past nominations and memberships at TUG. I honestly never imagined in my life form part of an outstanding group of intellectuals.

With this in mind I would like to put forward my nomination for the TUG Membership 2015.

A big thank you once more.

Answer (score 27):

I don't know whether I'm worthy, but [the ever friendly Paulo Cereda suggested I put my name down](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19441456#19441456) `:)`

I only joined TeX.SX two years ago or so, but I was immediately awed by how friendly, helpful, and knowledgeable the TeX.SX community is. From knowing nothing about Tex & friends, I eventually learned enough, thanks to the community, to put a couple of packages together and successfully submit them on CTAN (more to come...).

I remain active on the site ([especially](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a21891%20%5blistings%5d) in the [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) tag, but also in the [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz) tag), which feels a bit like *home*, at this stage. Here are some of the answers I'm most proud of:

- [Why doesn't TikZ's \foreach iterate over the last element of the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116980/why-doesnt-tikzs-foreach-iterate-over-the-last-element-of-the-list/116990#116990)
- [What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document/158816#158816)
- [Can the listings package be set up to highlight Prolog code like minted does?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161235/can-the-listings-package-be-set-up-to-highlight-prolog-code-like-minted-does/161237#161237)
- [Can the listings package highlight by regexp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/can-the-listings-package-highlight-by-regexp/159248#159248)
- [How can I produce the history graph of a Git repository in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125244/how-can-i-produce-the-history-graph-of-a-git-repository-in-latex/198345#198345)
- [Rindler coordinate chart (family of parametric curves) in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105822/rindler-coordinate-chart-family-of-parametric-curves-in-tikz/105857#105857)
- [Diagram of an Acoustic Doppler Current Profiler (ADCP) in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/diagram-of-an-acoustic-doppler-current-profiler-adcp-in-tikz/126098#126098)
- [Drawing of Sun–Earth–Moon system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116978/drawing-of-sun-earth-moon-system/117280#117280)
- [How to highlight all words of the form [0-9][A-Za-z0-9]* immediately following an equal sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/how-to-highlight-all-words-of-the-form-0-9a-za-z0-9-immediately-following-a/164297#164297)

I must confess that, although I have read and learned from several TUGboat articles, I have yet to become a TUG member... but what a great opportunity to join! I would be honoured to be one of the members representing TeX.SX in the TeX User Group, and I would be delighted to attend TeX-related conferences (time and funding permitting) wearing the "TeX.SX representative hat"... or a duck lifebuoy, in honour of Paulo.

---

**Edit**: Marc Van Dongen once gave me an idea that, I believe, would make for an interesting TUGboat article, but it's probably too early to announce it here. More details when I start cooking it :)

Comment: OP had better deliver in regards to a "duck lifebuoy" `:)`

Comment: @SeanAllred Lol. I knew I was going to regret writing that `:'(`

Comment: I don't know if it's wise enough to edit answers here too frequently with minor edits to jump up the thread/queue since  it may hinder others to have an even chance in voting

Comment: Your editing doesn't make your post jump up the queue/thread as far as I can see. In fact answers with the same score appear to be listed in order of last editing, with the oldest *highest* in the thread. So editing moves your post lower, which might be bad for you, but can scarcely be thought to be unfair. (Higher posts on the page presumably have the advantage, if there is one.)

Comment: @cfr I don't know if you ever had default(atleast in my case it shows by default) **active**  tab activated out of the `oldest` and `votes` options for the answer then Most recent edited posts popup in front page. Before voting started everyone is given time to putforth their strengths and contributions to TeX world. When Voting is _in progress_ IMO no edits are advisable unless really required because it skews/changes the voting pattern and criterion for which people had voted for.

Comment: @texenthusiast Maybe. The behaviour I'm seeing is the default for me. That is, I haven't changed anything. Since people can add their names during the voting period, I am not sure that edits are really off-limits. Of course, this is within reason. If somebody originally posts a bunch of promises or whatever and people vote, and then they remove or alter them, that would obviously be problematic. (E.g. 'I'll write x articles for TUG Boat' gets removed halfway through voting.) Note that people can also retract a vote or vote down if you edit your post, although obviously people may not revisit.

Answer (score 26):

I am submitting my name as the result of a concerted campaign in chat to persuade me to do so. I do not think I deserve to be nominated and so I cannot give any reasons in favour of my nomination. I have only been a member of the site for just over a year. I have learnt a lot and it has been fun. But I only joined because somebody reported that people could not typeset Polish with a font support package I'd published on CTAN, and I needed to know if the fonts themselves provided sufficient resources for Polish in order to determine whether or not an update would actually solve the problem. So it was all something of an accident, I really don't know what I'm doing, and I think there are many much more deserving candidates. I recommend voting for them.

[image: TUG cats]

```
\RequirePackage[rgb,pdftex,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont,cfr-lm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,backgrounds,shadows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pen}
\pgfdeclarelayer{corff}
\pgfsetlayers{background,corff,main,pen,foreground}
\makeatletter
% adapted (simplified version) from tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
  \tikzset{%
    on foreground layer/.style={%
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{foreground}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on foreground layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    on pen layer/.style={
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{pen}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on pen layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    on corff layer/.style={
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{corff}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on corff layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    stripiau cwt/.style={draw=#1, very thin, shorten >=-5mm, shorten <=-5mm, double=#1, double distance=3.5mm},
    stripiau corff/.style={very thin, draw=#1, fill=#1},
    trwyn/.style={circle, yshift=1.25mm, minimum width=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt},
    llenwi cath/.style={fill=#1},
    llygaid/.style n args=2{inner color=#1, outer color=#2, ultra thick, draw},
    pics/cath a/.style n args=5{
      code={
        [ultra thick]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{pen}% ref. workaround from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218166/ (Mark Wibrow)
          \begin{scope}[very thin]% [on pen layer={very thin}]
          \path [clip]
            (0,10mm) coordinate (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.75] (pp1) coordinate (pen2)
              arc (65:45:19mm and 20mm)  coordinate (pen3)
              arc (45:-60:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.05] (pp4) coordinate [pos=.4] (pp5) coordinate [pos=.45] (pp8) coordinate [pos=.75] (pp9)  coordinate (pen8)
              arc (-60:-90:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen10)
              arc (-90:-120:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen9)
              arc (-120:-225:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.25] (pp10) coordinate [pos=.55] (pp11) coordinate [pos=.6] (pp6) coordinate [pos=.95] (pp7) coordinate (pen4)
              arc (-225:-245:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen5)
              arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.25] (pp2)
              ;
          \path [stripiau corff=#1]
            (pp2) [out=-45, in=95] to ($(pen1) - (0,10mm)$) coordinate (pp3) [out=85, in=-135] to (pp1) |- +(5mm,5mm) -| cycle
            (pp4) [out=-135, in=25] to +(-7.5mm,-4mm) [out=-25, in=115] to (pp5) -| +(5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp7) [out=-45, in=155] to +(7.5mm,-4mm) [out=-155, in=65] to (pp6) -| +(-5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp8) [out=-135, in=-25] to +(-17.5mm,0mm) [out=-45, in=115] to (pp9) -| +(5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp11) [out=-45, in=-155] to +(17.5mm,0mm) [out=-135, in=65] to (pp10) -| +(-5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \path
          (pen2) ++(4mm,7.5mm) coordinate (pen6)
          (pen5) ++(-4mm,7.5mm) coordinate (pen7);
        \path [rounded corners=1pt, llenwi cath=#2]
          (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm)
            [out=80, in=-110] to (pen6) [out=-80, in=85] to
          (pen3) arc (45:-225:19mm and 20mm)
            [out=95, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to
          (pen5) arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm);
        \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
          \draw [rounded corners=1pt, ultra thick]
            (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm)
              [out=80, in=-110] to (pen6) [out=-80, in=85] to
            (pen3) arc (45:-225:19mm and 20mm)
              [out=95, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to
            (pen5) arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm);
        \end{scope}
         \path [name path=corff]
           (pen9) [out=-160, in=115] to ++(-10mm,-65mm) coordinate (corff2)
           (pen8) [out=-20, in=65] to coordinate [pos=.25] (corff4) ++(+10mm,-65mm)coordinate (corff1)
             [out=-115, in=0] to ($(corff1 -| pen1) + (0,-10mm)$) coordinate (corff3)
             [out=180, in=-65] to (corff2)
           ;
         \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
          \draw
            (pen10) -- ++(0,7.5mm) coordinate (ceg1)
              [out=-45, in=180] to +(5mm,-2.5mm) coordinate (ceg2)
              [out=0, in=-100] to +(2.5mm,3.5mm) coordinate (ceg3)
             ;
          \draw
            (ceg1)
              [out=-135, in=0] to +(-5mm,-2.5mm) coordinate (ceg4)
              [out=180, in=-80] to +(-2.5mm,3.5mm) coordinate (ceg5)
            ;
          \path (ceg1)
            node (trwyn1) [trwyn, anchor=west] {}
            node (trwyn2) [trwyn, anchor=east] {};
          \draw
            ($(trwyn1)!1/2!(trwyn2)$) coordinate (trwyn) [out=10,in=140] to +(25mm,7.5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-10, in=120] to +(.5mm,-5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-40, in=130] to +(-1.5mm,-5mm)
            ;
          \draw
            (trwyn) [out=170,in=40] to +(-25mm,7.5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-170, in=60] to +(-.5mm,-5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-140, in=50] to +(1.5mm,-5mm)
            ;
          \path (ceg1)
            node (trwyn1) [trwyn, draw, ball color=#5, anchor=west] {}
            node (trwyn2) [trwyn, draw, ball color=#5, anchor=east] {};
         \end{scope}
          \draw [name path=coesau, ultra thick, llenwi cath=#2]
            ($(pen10)!1/3!(corff3)$) coordinate (coesau) -- (corff3) [out=-90, in=135] to ++(.25mm,-1mm) coordinate (coes1)
            arc (180:360:1.5mm and 1.5mm) coordinate (coes2)
            arc (180:360:1.75mm and 2mm) coordinate (coes3)
            arc (180:360:1.5mm and 1.5mm) coordinate (coes4)
            [out=90, in=-75] to ($(corff3) + (5.5mm,2.5mm)$) coordinate (coes9)
            [out=105, in=-90] to ($(coes9 |- coesau) + (3.5mm,1.5mm)$) coordinate (coes de)
            (corff3) [out=-90, in=45] to ++(-.25mm,-1mm) coordinate (coes8)
            arc (0:-180:1.5mm and 1.5mm) coordinate (coes5)
            arc (0:-180:1.75mm and 2mm) coordinate (coes6)
            arc (0:-180:1.5mm and 1.5mm) coordinate (coes7)
            [out=90, in=-105] to ($(corff3) + (-5.5mm,2.5mm)$) coordinate (coes10)
            [out=75, in=-90] to ($(coes10 |- coesau) + (-3.5mm,1.5mm)$) coordinate (coes chwith)
            ;
        \begin{scope}[on background layer={ultra thick}]
         \path [name path=cwt, draw, name intersections={of=corff and coesau, name=cc}, llenwi cath=#2]
           (cc-2)
             [out=0, in=-115] to coordinate [pos=.5] (cwt1 hanner) ($(corff1) + (1.5mm,-2.5mm)$) coordinate (cwt1)
             [out=65, in=-80]  to
               coordinate [pos=.125] (cwt2 hanner hanner hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.25] (cwt2 hanner hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.375] (cwt2 hanner hanner a hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.5] (cwt2 hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.625] (cwt2 hanner a hanner hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.75] (cwt2 hanner a hanner)
               coordinate [pos=.875] (cwt2 hanner a hanner a hanner) ($(corff4) + (7.5mm,0)$) coordinate (cwt2)
             [out=100, in=0] to coordinate [pos=.5] (cwt3 hanner)  +(-2.5mm,12.5mm) coordinate (cwt3)
             [out=180, in=100] to coordinate [pos=.5] (cwt4 hanner) (corff4)
             ;
        \end{scope}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}% ref. workaround from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218166/ (Mark Wibrow)
          \begin{scope}[ultra thick]%[on background layer={ultra thick}]
           \path [clip]
             (cc-2)
               [out=0, in=-115] to (cwt1)
               [out=65, in=-80]  to  (cwt2)
               [out=100, in=0] to  (cwt3)
               [out=180, in=100] to (corff4)
               ;
           \foreach \i/\j in {cwt3 hanner/cwt4 hanner,cwt2/corff4}
             \path [stripiau cwt=#1]
               (\i) [out=130, in=-50] to (\j);
           \foreach \i in {cwt1 hanner, cwt1, cwt2 hanner hanner hanner, cwt2 hanner hanner, cwt2 hanner hanner a hanner, cwt2 hanner, cwt2 hanner a hanner hanner, cwt2 hanner a hanner, cwt2 hanner a hanner a hanner}
             \path [stripiau cwt=#1]
               (\i) [out=130, in=-50] to +(-20mm,2.5mm);
          \end{scope}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
         \path [draw, ultra thick]
           (cc-2)
             [out=0, in=-115] to (cwt1)
             [out=65, in=-80]  to  (cwt2)
             [out=100, in=0] to  (cwt3)
             [out=180, in=100] to (corff4)
             ;
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{corff}% ref. workaround from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218166/ (Mark Wibrow)
          \begin{scope}[ultra thick]%[on corff layer={ultra thick}]
            \draw [clip]
               (pen8) [out=-20, in=65]
                 to coordinate [pos=.05] (cff1) coordinate [pos=.15] (cff2)  coordinate [pos=.2] (cff3)  coordinate [pos=.325] (cff4)  coordinate [pos=.4] (cff5)  coordinate [pos=.5] (cff6)  coordinate [pos=.55] (cff7)  coordinate [pos=.65] (cff8)  coordinate [pos=.7] (cff9)  coordinate [pos=.8] (cff10)   coordinate [pos=.85] (cff11)  coordinate [pos=.95] (cff12)
               (corff1) [out=-115, in=0]
                 to coordinate [pos=.25] (cff13) coordinate [pos=.5] (cff14) coordinate [pos=.75] (cff15)
               (cc-2) -- (cc-3) [out=180, in=-65]
                 to coordinate [pos=.25] (cff35) coordinate [pos=.5] (cff34) coordinate [pos=.75] (cff33) (corff2) [out=115, in=-160]
               to coordinate [pos=.05] (cff32) coordinate [pos=.15] (cff31)  coordinate [pos=.2] (cff30)  coordinate [pos=.3] (cff29)  coordinate [pos=.35] (cff28)  coordinate [pos=.45] (cff27)  coordinate [pos=.5] (cff26)  coordinate [pos=.6] (cff25)  coordinate [pos=.675] (cff24)  coordinate [pos=.8] (cff23)   coordinate [pos=.85] (cff22)  coordinate [pos=.95] (cff21) (pen9)
               arc (-120:-60:19mm and 20mm);
            \path [llenwi cath=#2]
               (pen8) [out=-20, in=65] to (corff1) [out=-115, in=0] to (cc-2) -- (cc-3) [out=180, in=-65] to (corff2) [out=115, in=-160] to (pen9) arc (-120:-60:19mm and 20mm);
            \draw [stripiau corff=#1]
              (cff1) [out=-135, in=-10] to +(-10mm,-7.5mm) [out=-30, in=170] to (cff2) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff3) [out=-155, in=-20] to +(-15mm,-7.5mm) [out=-35, in=140] to (cff4) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff5) [out=150, in=20] to +(-20mm,-2.5mm) [out=10, in=130] to (cff6) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff7) [out=125, in=-40] to +(-15mm,2.5mm) [out=-50, in=100] to (cff8) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff9) [out=115, in=-60] to +(-15mm,3.75mm) [out=-70, in=95] to (cff10) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff11) [out=105, in=-70] to +(-15mm,5mm) [out=-80, in=90] to (cff12) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (corff1) [out=100, in=-80] to +(-12.5mm,8.5mm) [out=-85, in=90] to (cff13) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff14) [out=90, in=-90] to +(-8.5mm,7.5mm) [out=-100, in=90] to (cff15) -| +(5mm,0) |- cycle
              ;
            \draw [stripiau corff=#1]
              (cff21) [out=-45, in=-170] to +(10mm,-7.5mm) [out=-150, in=10] to (cff22) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff23) [out=-25, in=-150] to +(15mm,-7.5mm) [out=-145, in=40] to (cff24) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff25) [out=30, in=160] to +(20mm,-2.5mm) [out=170, in=50] to (cff26) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff27) [out=55, in=-140] to +(15mm,2.5mm) [out=-130, in=80] to (cff28) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff29) [out=65, in=-120] to +(15mm,3.75mm) [out=-110, in=85] to (cff30) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff31) [out=75, in=-110] to +(15mm,5mm) [out=-100, in=90] to (cff32) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (corff2) [out=80, in=-100] to +(12.5mm,8.5mm) [out=-95, in=90] to (cff33) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (cff34) [out=90, in=-90] to +(8.5mm,7.5mm) [out=-80, in=90] to (cff35) -| +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              ;
          \end{scope}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \begin{scope}[on corff layer={ultra thick}]
          \draw
             (pen8) [out=-20, in=65] to (corff1) [out=-115, in=0] to (cc-2) -- (cc-3) [out=180, in=-65] to (corff2) [out=115, in=-160] to (pen9) arc (-120:-60:19mm and 20mm);
        \end{scope}
          \draw [llygaid={#3}{#4}]
          ({$(pen1)!2/5!(pen10)$} -| {$(pen8)!3/4!(pen4)$}) coordinate (llygad chwith)
            ++(-5mm,0) coordinate (llygad chwith 1) [out=20, in=180] to ++(6mm,2.5mm) coordinate (llygad chwith 2) [out=0, in=120] to ++(4mm,-2.5mm)
            [out=-120, in=0] to ++(-4mm,-2.5mm) [out=180, in=-20] to ++(-6mm,2.5mm)
          ;
          \draw [llygaid={#3}{#4}]
            ({$(pen1)!2/5!(pen10)$} -| {$(pen9)!3/4!(pen3)$}) coordinate (llygad de)
              ++(5mm,0) coordinate (llygad de 1) [out=160, in=0] to ++(-6mm,2.5mm) coordinate (llygad de 2) [out=180, in=40] to ++(-4mm,-2.5mm)
              [out=-40, in=180] to ++(4mm,-2.5mm) [out=0, in=-160] to ++(6mm,2.5mm)
          ;
          \fill [ball color=black] (llygad chwith 1 -| llygad chwith 2) circle (2.5mm);
          \fill [ball color=black] (llygad de 1 -| llygad de 2) circle (2.5mm);
          \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
            \draw [shorten >=1pt]
              ($(pen2)!7/10!(pen3)$) coordinate (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6);
            \draw [shorten >=1pt]
              ($(pen5)!7/10!(pen4)$) coordinate (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7);
          \end{scope}
          \begin{scope}% llenwi clust de
            \clip (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6) [out=-110, in=80] to (pen2) |- cycle;
            \path [stripiau corff=#1, rounded corners=1pt]
              (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6) [out=-110, in=80] to (pen2) arc (65:45:19mm and 20mm)
              ;
          \end{scope}
          \begin{scope}% llenwi clust chwith
            \clip (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to (pen5) |- cycle;
            \path [stripiau corff=#1, rounded corners=1pt]
              (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to (pen5) arc (-245:-225:19mm and 20mm)
              ;
          \end{scope}
          \node (bathodyn) [minimum width=10mm, inner sep=0pt, circle, circular glow={fill=#1}, text=#2!50, font=\large\bfseries, align=center] at ([yshift=10mm]coesau) {I \ding{164}\\TUG};
          % dim yn ddefnyddiol ar hyn o bryd ond gobeithio bynnan nhw ar ôl iddyn nhw fix the bug!
          \coordinate (-pen) at (pen1);
          \coordinate (-clust chwith) at (pen7);
          \coordinate (-clust de) at (pen6);
          \coordinate (-cwt) at (cwt2);
          \coordinate (-coes chwith) at (coes6);
          \coordinate (-coes de) at (coes3);
          \coordinate (-corff chwith) at (corff2);
          \coordinate (-corff de) at (corff1);
        }
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \colorlet{cath1}{blue!50!gray!75}
  \colorlet{cath2}{cath1!50}
  \colorlet{cath3}{DarkOrchid4}
  \colorlet{cath4}{cath3!50}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid1}{Yellow1}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid2}{DarkOrange3}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid3}{Chartreuse1}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid4}{Green4}
  \colorlet{lliw trwyn1}{LightPink2}
  \colorlet{lliw trwyn2}{HotPink2}
  \colorlet{cath5}{LavenderBlush3}
  \colorlet{cath6}{LavenderBlush4}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [xscale=-1] {cath a={cath1}{cath2}{lliw llygaid3}{lliw llygaid4}{lliw trwyn1}};
    \pic at (57.5mm,0) {cath a={cath6}{cath5}{lliw llygaid1}{lliw llygaid2}{lliw trwyn2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I could upvote again, I would do for the Tikz-Cats ;-) ... Symbolic +10 ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer They were there before but didn't appear themselves. [It seemed inappropriate to me to post the compiled version originally.] I now have a library for cats which would have simplified the code a lot!

Comment: Make a package from your library please, if you have not already done so! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The `pic`s all have Welsh names, and the code is also rather linguistically entangled. I'm not sure that CTAN would be happy about it. Also, it does not use key-value syntax for specifying the cats but just a series of arguments. So it is not very user-friendly.

Comment: ...... so far ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Which bit? They are definitely Welsh cats!

Answer (score 22):

I have been a member of this site for some four years now and have a strong interest in TeX. I would be honoured to be nominated and I will submit an article to TUG. It will be an honor to be a member of the community.

Answer (score 22):

I will nominate myself for a TUG membership.

My active involvement in the TeX community - mainly on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) - has taught me a great deal. It would be an honour to be granted a membership to TUG as support their goals:

1. To encourage and expand the use of TeX, LaTeX, Metafont and related systems.
2. To ensure the integrity and portability of TeX, LaTeX, Metafont and related systems.
3. To foster innovation in high-quality electronic document preparation.

I am looking forward to another year of activities that would include the above.

Answer (score 18):

My apologies for being so late with my submission (I've been very busy sorting out housing for a new job nearly 1000 miles away), but I'd like to humbly put my name into that hat for TUG membership, a privilege I have thoroughly enjoyed this past year in reading and learning from the excellent articles and resources available to TUG members.

I've been using LaTeX for about four years now.  I was at one time an incredibly active member of this site in particular, but this has since waned due to time and network constraints with my (old) job.  I am a huge supporter of TeX use in industry and have continually 'evangelized' TeX and its advantages in my field especially.  I've even implemented a TeX-based reporting workflow for my (old) job `:)` (They like it very much!)

I'm hoping the time and support of my new job will finally allow me to continue writing and blogging in support of TeX and Friends (along with contributing further to this site) and I would be honored to be a representative for a platform I am so broadly passionate about.  I truly believe that the presentation and mechanics of StackExchange sites is the best resource available to those interested in TeX through the medium of traditional, merit-based 'advertisement by example', as I've successfully done significantly for at least two of my coworkers since I started this (old) job in June 2014.

I'm hoping to be blessed with listening ears at my new job to continue the growth (and much-needed support) of TeX and related systems `:)` to an audience already familiar with the StackExchange format, to be blessed with the means to use my newly-acquired PTO to further the industry influence of TeX, and to encourage and empower the amazing user base (TeX.SX!) that inspires its continued development.

---

After thinking about it for a little while, I think I have enough material / experience to write an article on TeX in industry *today* and what steps may tip the tables in TeX's favor in the business world.  On a related note, if such an article already exists, would someone *please* post a link?  The idea sounds fascinating!

Comment: Nice to see you on the list too! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

I'll be so brave to nominate myself. While I don't participate so much in answering questions recently, I concentrate on the community work: flagging, commenting, editing, following both the local and the big meta actively.

I also try to organize my time so that I can attend the TUG meeting in Darmstadt and hopefully give a talk there (I can give a talk about TeX.SX if I'm asked to, otherwise I have another thing in mind).

If I don't get nominated, I will get my TUG membership on my own, and I may cancel my nomination in the case there are other people on the list who can make a good use of the membership.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to a kind notice from [Jubobs](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs), I discovered the existence of this TUG membership list. But it was after the 'nomination' phase and I hesitated to put my name on the list afterwards. After [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) also asked me to put my name on this list, I do it now quite lately before the door closes. I apologize for rushing in   unpunctual.

I've been using LaTeX since 25 years now. Since that time many software tools and languages were invented. More than once I thought *'I should dig into this or that new stuff when I have time'*. But then the cool new stuff was *outdated* before I found time to study it. The funny thing is that TeX/LaTeX still is present quite fresh and is not replaced by the next cool thing :-)

I started using LaTeX to write my PhD thesis. The last years, my connections with LaTeX have become much stronger. Meanwhile, I use it for nearly everything :-) All written material I use as a professor for Mathematics is done in LaTeX and I do my very best to evangelize my colleages in this direction ;-)

I'm the author of an [introduction book for LaTeX](https://www.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/buch.html?&titel=latex) and of some packages; [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) is the most time-killing one. I give lectures in LaTeX for my students and I try to be helpful at TeX.SX. Since I joined TeX.SX, I also learned more from all the other helpful members since in many years before. 2015 will be a very LaTeX-centric year for me since I have plans for a new package.

So, I would feel very pleased and honoured to be a member of the TUG community. At least, I want to fill up this list: StackExchange should not have the impression that there is not enough interest on a corporate membership - there surely is.

Comment: Corrected the spelling error in Jubobs' name ;-) ... Since nomination of other users is difficults (see my comment below Joseph Wright's 'question' I did not nominee others, but if possible, I would nominated you too. Thanks to Jubobs for poking you ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the correction - that was the worst place to put an error in (grmbl). I hope Jubobs has not seen it ;-)

Comment: I won't tell him ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Joseph just linked me to this page and... oh, it's already the last day to go. Well, I did not know about these TeX.SX representatives until this very moment but actually I like this idea.

I am not such an advanced programmer like many others on this site but I like helping, testing, calling into question, treating super pedantic stuff ;-)... If I have time, I can get quite busy for TeX.SX and I like that. As I love the idea of the big open source community (and love TeX) but am not even able to program in TeX, I believe that it could be nice for TUG *and* me, to get me as a new member. At least, I would like to try that in order to widen my horizon. And I could get a platform to get involved and to give back for all I already took from you guys.

I would be honoured to get nominated here. And, yeah, Darmstadt is really not far away from here... Maybe I can make it.

Answer (score 12):

I've been using LaTeX since the late 1990s. Before that, I used to 'typeset' documents using Wordstar clones (VDE and later ZDE) on an Amstrad CPC. These had basic markup for bold, large, etc. so they weren't a million miles away from LaTeX (at least for basic
documents), but the final output could only be viewed by printing, in my case using a 9-pin dot matrix printer: 2 minutes per page. Those were the days. I tried Word for a while, but soon developed a visceral hatred for software in which the user's prior actions are not easily traceable. These days I use LaTeX for just about every document I create.

I found TeX.SX after discovering what I thought was [a bug in amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5915/2417) (it was). I've always been amazed by the speed with which difficult problems are solved, though this has its downside and I've been known to utter the odd swear word when my own nearly complete answer is beaten to it by a faster typing user.

I'm more than willing to be more involved with the TeX community, but I'm not sure what contributions I can make.  It's probably fair to say that I know more than the average LaTeX user, but I am by no means an expert.