# TUG Membership: Names for 2016

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tug, sponsorship

StackExchange [continues to support TUG with corporate membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/annual-tex-user-group-membership-question-2015-edition) (many thanks). With that come eight individual memberships that can be given out to members of the community. The time has come to select our representatives for 2016. (See [TUG Membership: Names for 2015](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/tug-membership-names-for-2015) for last year's selection.)

I'd like to ask people to put themselves forward. There are *no restrictions* on standing other than having to be a member of the TeX StackExchange site. The existing 'representatives' are very welcome to put their names forward to continue. [Note: I've called the people we put forward 'representatives', but that's mainly because I can't think of a better term. Nominees should not feel the need to represent TeX-sx other than being members of the site and therefore interested in TeX in some way!]  There is *no need* to have any particular level of site reputation, TeX experience or wider 'reason' to put yourself forward other than an interest in TeX.

You may nominate others but the mod team will need confirmation from the nominee that they are happy before voting starts. The mod team will check this with any such nominees.

The model for selection of representatives is as follows. We will have a two stage process, first 'nomination' then 'election'. The first phase runs for five days, until 2100 GMT on 2016-02-01. Each person who wishes to be considered should post an answer, where they can (if they wish) say what makes them a good choice. They should then immediately delete their answer. Please don't vote on any answers during this phase: any votes cast will be ignored.

In the second phase, all of the answers will be undeleted, and everyone should take a look at these answers and vote for deserving candidates: remember there are eight places available! Again, there will be five days to vote, ending 2100 GMT on 2016-02-06. At that stage, the top eight names will be forwarded to the StackExchange community staff for notification to TUG.

In the event of a tie in number of votes, the mod team will decide which of the tied members are put forward to StackExchange. The mod team may also include additional names if at the end of the voting process there are fewer than eight nominees with positive scores.

---

Voting stage: Everyone is welcome to vote for as many or as few candidates as they wish. Remember that there are a total of eight places available to be selected. New nominations can be added during the voting phase.

---

At the end of the voting period, the tallies were:

- [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr), 30
- [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd), 29
- [michal.h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21), 28
- [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi), 27
- [Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4778/alenanno), 26
- [Przemysław Scherwentke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26134/przemys%C5%82aw-scherwentke), 24
- [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko), 24
- [samcarter](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter), 9

There are exactly eight names here, so all will be sent to the StackOverflow staff to be forwarded to TUG.

Comment: 'Nomination phase' comments removed: please _vote_ on the nominations now visible :-) (Thanks to all those whose suggested nominations, of course.)

Comment: Can I nominate Alenanno? I thought there was a nomination, but it seems I was confused.

Comment: @cfr Yep! You can. :D

Comment: Why we have only 7 nominations? I request people to nominate themselves so that we use all the slots available for us by stackexchange. Let us not waste the opportunity guys. Come on!

Comment: @HarishKumar: What about you? Do you have a membership already? ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Remember that the mod team reserve the right to add additional names to the list if there are spaces

Comment: Congrats everybody! I'm sure you'll love the TUGboat! :)

Comment: Thank you! :-))

Comment: Thank you! I can not believe, that I receive 24 (as stated above)/ 25 (as I see at my answer) votes! Best regards to all!

Comment: As of today, TUG has confirmed receipt of all of this year's representatives' information. Let me know if any problems crop up. Thank you all for being awesome, and enjoy!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks. But I already had my chance. Let others take the benefit too. :)

Comment: @JosephWright: I remember :). Glad that all eight slots are filled and that too with awesome candidates. :)

Answer (score 29):

As suggested by Ulrike I put my name on the list. I have been a member of dante for about 10 years and of tex.sx for 2 years. At the moment my main tags are the KOMA-Script ones. While I am answering a question I also use this example to test the beta version of KOMA-Script. I am also active in some German forums like TeXwelt.

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaay!

Answer (score 29):

I'm honoured to have been hwyaden-nominated by Paulo. I am reluctant to take advantage of this since I have enjoyed the benefit of a subscription this year and think that others should have their turns. However, since barbara has urged me to put my name forward despite this, as there are more spots available than there are nominees. (Though I'm not sure this is a reason to give me a second turn.)

I enjoy reading TUG Boat and I would be very pleased to enjoy another subscription. However, I would urge that preference be given to those who have not received a membership before.

My most popular question is [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255709/) and [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/) to it is my second most popular.

That said, popularity is fickle and scarcely a reliable indicator of quality or, indeed, of seriousness. (The unconvinced should note [my most popular answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266179/) before protesting this assertion.)

I have particular interests in support for 'traditional' TeX fonts, which can be used with engines such as TeX and pdfTeX, and in typesetting logic and tree diagrams.

I am the author of the following font support packages:

- [nfssext-cfr](http://ctan.org/pkg/nfssext-cfr) which extends the extension of the New Font Selection Scheme provided by Philipp Lehman as part of [The Font Installation Guide](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide). Several of my font packages use this to provide intuitive access to weights, widths, shapes and styles not supported out-of-the-box by the standard LaTeX-2e font commands. For example, `\plstyle` to switch to proportional, lining figures or `\textsi{<text>}` to typeset `<text>` in italic small-caps.
- Three packages which extend or provide LaTeX-2e interfaces for fonts already distributed as part of standard TeX distributions:

  - [cfr-lm](http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-lm) which provides extended access to the Latin Modern fonts e.g. italic small-caps, alternative widths and weights, upright italic and all four styles of figures.
  - [cfr-initials](http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials) which provides LaTeX packages supporting access to the various decorative fonts provided by [initials](http://ctan.org/pkg/initials).
  - [ebgaramond-maths](http://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond-maths) which provides limited support for the use of EB Garamond 12 in maths mode and was originally a response to a question here.
- Several packages which provide support for fonts from the Arkandis Digital Foundry (ADF), including type1 versions of the fonts themselves:

  - [adforn](http://ctan.org/pkg/adforn)
  - [adfsymbols](http://ctan.org/pkg/adfsymbols)
  - [baskervaldadf](http://ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldadf)
  - [berenisadf](http://ctan.org/pkg/berenisadf) (including specialist (i.e. hacked) support for the Welsh characters Ŵŵ and Ŷŷ)
  - [electrumadf](http://ctan.org/pkg/electrumadf) (in all its many weights!)
  - [libris](http://ctan.org/pkg/libris)
  - [romandeadf](http://ctan.org/pkg/romandeadf)
  - [venturisadf](http://ctan.org/pkg/venturisadf) (three serif and two sans serif families, including titling and swash)

I'm currently working on three 'proper' LaTeX packages (i.e. not fonts), two based on [forest](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) and developed in response to questions here. Now the new version has been published to CTAN, I hope to update the code in my experimental versions and will upload **prooftrees** and **justtrees** as soon as I find the time to write documentation and the courage to do so.

Also, I sometimes use TikZ to draw [cats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/219610#219610) and [cauldrons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244368/tikz-draw-a-cooking-pot/244378#244378). Though whether this is a reason to vote for me or against me, I can't really say.

[image: TUG cats]

[Code for this picture is around somewhere. Ask if curious and you can't find it. I now use a custom cat code TikZ library, but that's based on answers I've posted here somewhere.]

Comment: Cwac, said the hwyaden! `:)`

Comment: Cwac, cwacio ;) @PauloCereda

Comment: ooh `\usetikzlibrary{cats}`

Comment: @PauloCereda Actually, to be honest, it's `\usetikzlibrary{cathod}` but, yes, that's the general idea ;).

Answer (score 27):

Yo', Egreg and Johannes B insisted to nominate myself. I am active on TeX.sx for five years,  originally to find some help for my first LaTeX package [biblatex-iso690](https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690), I was hooked since then. I happened to create some packages which are included on CTAN, most notably `tex4ebook` for TeX to ebook conversion and `odsfile`, LuaLaTeX package for reading OpenDocument Spreadsheet files.

My top voted answer is just  an [example from xcoffins manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover/17580#17580), which confirms the fact that number of votes is inversely proportional to time and energy spent on an answer. Some more useful answers include [Mathjax powered HTML from LaTeX siurce](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html/68962#68962), [semantic web in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55779/is-there-a-software-in-ubuntu-that-can-analyse-the-cross-references-theorems-l/56394#56394), or [optimizing set of images layout using Lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2891).

Comment: Woooohoooo too!

Comment: An example from a manual sounds pretty good. Did you check the link I gave to the [answer of *mine* with most votes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266179/)? If that doesn't convince people the numbers are meaningless, I figure nothing will.

Comment: Michal is also very active in dealing with `tex4ht` (`htlatex`), which is a very valuable contribution!

Answer (score 26):

I propose my self. I'm LaTeX user since my degree project, long time ago, and I've been actively participating in this site and some other latex-related-lists like Cervantex, comp.text.tex, miktex-users, ...

Although I think that it is not my better answer, my most voted answer until now is [How to prevent pgfplots from using the 10^n notation for axis ticks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/how-to-prevent-pgfplots-from-using-the-10n-notation-for-axis-ticks/29929#29929) which shows that I'm good [reading manuals](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6507/1952) ;-)

I don't plan to attend any TeX conference or writing any paper related, but I would like to be able to read some TUGboat on time and not next year.

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaay too!

Answer (score 25):

As suggested by cfr and encouraged by Christian Hupfer and Paulo Cereda I put my name on the list.

First time I use LaTeX about 25 years ago when wrote an article for IEE conference. After than I use it on regular basis for writing articles, presentation, examines, expertise memos and text books. Recently I use TikZ with big joy in (re)drawing all my illustration. For my text books and Ph.D. thesis of my students I developed document classes. During this years I gain some experiences with LaTeX, which I glad to share with beginners. With this I become more active recent year also here, on SE. For me the SE I is rich treasure of knowledge, from which I learn a lot.

Regardless if I will elected or not, I will continue in my spare time with my activity on SE.

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaay!

Answer (score 24):

> **[Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4778/alenanno)**

This bloke. ^^

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaay!

Comment: Paulo, the spokesman of ... Alenanno/Alejandro :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: *Must... resist... singing... Lady Gaga's... song...* `:)`

Comment: Cwac! @PauloCereda

Comment: Thanks to everyone. :')

Answer (score 23):

I will nominate myself for a TUG membership. I am a member of GUST: http://www.gust.org.pl/ and this helps me to understand, how restricted is my TeX knowledge, but in the same time helps to push boundaries.

I would like to have access to current TUG articles, but TUG membership is rather expensive for me. Certainly, I can wait, but especially "TeX friends" need much time to be assimilated.

Here I am trying to give answers to easy or intermediate questions. One of them, not the best, even not accepted, is now to the memory of Kees van der Laan: [Censoring Curse Words with Grawlixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/censoring-curse-words-with-grawlixes/117859#117859). His beautiful article in GUST Bulletin helped me to understand FIFO queues in TeX.

Comment: Woooooohoooooo!

Answer (score 14):

The last day of the election and only 7 nominees for 8 positions? That is kind of sad, so I will add myself to the nominees, even if I am much less qualified than the others -- no TeX development or something, just a user.

I am an enthusiastic LaTeX user since the beginning of my studies in 2007, and after years of reading Q&As on this site, I actively joined it in 2013 when I wanted to know

[How to number slides with an increasing number of digits of pi?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132370/36296)

and I got incredibly good and fast answers to my question, so I stayed and mostly answer beamer questions.

For me, the favourite answer of mine is probably

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171482/36296

This might not be the one with [most votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165087/36296), but with the most colours :)

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaay!

Comment: @PauloCereda Thanks, quack!

Comment: @samcarter: Can you add even more colours to your favorite answer? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried at the time when writing the answer, but there would not fit more pages on a single screenshot :( I absolutely need a bigger screen!

Comment: @samcarter: Well anyway -- nice to have you on the show !