# TUG Representatives for 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tug

As a community we have institutional membership of TUG paid for by StackOverflow. (Thanks to StackOverflow for this support and to [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) for [the initial idea](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/do-we-want-stack-exchange-to-become-an-institutional-member-of-the-tug)!) The membership entitles us to nominate eight people to benefit directly from this, receiving copies of [*TUGBoat*](http://tug.org/tugboat/) and so on. As in [previous years](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/tug-membership-names-for-2016), the aim of this question is to solicit nominations for those places.

In the first stage, I would like to ask for nominations for the places. Nominations should be made by posting an answer here with any reasoning you like, then immediately deleting the answer. In a second stage, I will undelete all of the answers to allow the community to vote: any 'stray' votes before the second phase *will be ignored*. Nominations can be made by the 'candidate' themselves or you can nominate someone else. In the latter situation the mod team will check that the nominee is happy to appear in the 'ballot'.

There is no restriction on standing in the ballot beyond needing to be a member of TeX-sx as-of this morning (0900 GMT on 2017-02-07). In particular, the aim of the memberships here is to allow TeX knowledge to be disseminated: candidates do not have to have 'strong' TeX knowledge, 'community standing' or similar.

The first phase (nominations) will run until 2200 GMT on 2017-02-11, after which there will be a five day voting phase. In the event of a tie in votes, the mod team will decide which name goes forward. The mod team may also include additional names if at the end of the voting process there are fewer than eight nominees with positive scores.

---

The voting phase is open until 2200 GMT on 2017-02-16. Additional nominations may be added during this phase. At the end of this period the top eight names will be passed to the StackOverflow staff. (Note: at the time of writing there are nominations which have not been made 'active' as the nominees have not yet confirmed they are happy to go forward.)

---

At the end of the voting period the tallies were

- [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) 21
- [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) 19
- [Przemysław Scherwentke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26134/przemys%c5%82aw-scherwentke) 18
- [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes) 16
- [Gustavo Mezzetti](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69818/gustavo-mezzetti) 16
- [Sašo Živanović](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16819/sa%c5%a1o-%c5%bdivanovi%c4%87) 16
- [Sam Carter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) 13
- [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko) 12
- [Jan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120477/jan) 11

With eight places available, Jan misses out (sorry) and the others are selected: we will let the staff know.

Comment: Joseph, in order to make the most of this thrilling opportunity, the admin team should check (if possible), if the nominated person is already TUG member.  In that case, it would make sense to me, to exclude those persons from nominees and give others the chance.  What does the community say?

Comment: @Jan That's one of the reasons for saying that nominations by third parties are checked. To be honest, I favour purely self-nominations but in the past there has been a feeling that they should also be allowed by others.

Comment: Thank you! (I hope that this is the correct place).

Answer (score 21):

I'd like to nominate [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr), to ask her to help us to create a `tikzducks` package.

Comment: +1, because I'm not allowed to upvote my own answer.

Answer (score 19):

Herr Professor Paulinho van Duck would like to be a TUG member!

Since he lives at my home at the moment, he asked me to write down my name here.

I accept the membership on his behalf!

Special thanks to Paulo Cereda, Ulrike Fischer, Christian Hupfer, yo' and Jan for their kindness!

Comment: If he gets the membership he should host a regular short column called "Duckboat"  (e.g. about witches in math) in the TUGboat!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are a GENIUS!

Answer (score 16):

Generally, I don't  like nominating myself for anything, but TUG membership is  an exception.

Tex.sx says that over 1 million of people viewed my helpful posts. My access to TUGboat should enlarge this number. And last but not least: they had ducks in TUGboat last year!

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to nominate [Sašo Živanović](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16819/sa%c5%a1o-%c5%bdivanovi%c4%87) who has created the wonderful `forest` package, which now dominates all tree related answers. 
[image]

Comment: ooh I love this tree! `:)`

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to nominate [Gustavo Mezzetti](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69818/gustavo-mezzetti).

Since he gave us the wonderful package `\halloweenmath`, he deserves a TUG membership!

[image]

Comment: +1, because I'm not allowed to upvote my own answer.

Answer (score 15):

## [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes)

^^ this bloke. `:)`

Answer (score 11):

I nominee Sam Carter, as Christian Hupfer was kindly asking for.

**EDIT ([@samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) speaking):**

Thank you very much for nominating me! I am honoured to be this years representative and I would happily do it again. However when casting your votes, please first consider the candidates, which did not yet have the privilege to be our representative at TUG.

If I counted correctly, my last year's *duck number* on TeX.SE was 8, from which https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344842/36296 was the most fun to write. I hope I can increase this number this year (currently I'm only at 2).

Comment: +1 for Sam, but as I made the proposal, I am not allowed to vote on my own answer.  Sorry Sam.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to nominate [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko) because I like his answers.

Comment: +1, because I'm not allowed to upvote my own answer.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to nominate [Jan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/252495/jan) because he is too modest to do it by himself.

Comment: +1, because I'm not allowed to upvote my own answer.