# Annual TeX User Group membership question, 2015 edition

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tug

I'm Pops, one of the Community Managers at Stack Exchange. It's a new calendar year, which means it's time once more to either renew or cancel our TeX User Group institutional membership. Based on your enthusiasm [last year](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/should-we-keep-our-tex-user-group-membership), I'm pretty sure my inbox is going to contain a lot of the word "renew" over the next few hours, but just to be sure: what say ye?

Remember, one of the most direct benefits of membership for the community is the ability to [select eight users for individual membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-we-choose-tex-se-members-for-representing-se-in-the-tug). Here's how that worked out last year: [TUG Membership: Names for 2014](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/tug-membership-names-for-2014)

Comment: There's a little added variation this year.  If a new member declares that an existing member was responsible for their joining, that (existing) member will receive a small thank-you token from TUG, and his/her name will be placed into a pool from which, at the end of 2015, one name will be selected as recipient of an original drawing by Duane Bibby, the artist whose illustrations grace the pages of the TeXbook, the LaTeX manual, and many other TeX-related venues.  For more details, see [this web site](https://www.tug.org/membership/).  (Don't use my name; I'm not eligible.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not sure if that applies to the 'reps' we will pick if the StackExchange 'site' membership gets renewed, but it is of course very well worth knowing!

Comment: @JosephWright -- if the "reps" picked fill out the membership form, the 2015 form has a space for this, so it should apply.  Or whoever is collecting address information for the "reps" can ask for that information as well for anyone new to tug; it's not against the rules.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, we're still benefiting from our TUG membership. Let's renew!

Comment: Okay, this is a clear winner. Consider the membership renewed! (And maybe start a new nomination post?)

Comment: OK, I've started a nomination thread: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/tug-membership-names-for-2015

Comment: pops pls... `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda -1 for not figuring out a way to include a programmatically generated duck in your comment. _Very_ disappointing!

Comment: @Pops: Oh no! `:)`

Answer (score -3):

Nah, this has outlived its usefulness. No need to stick around for this year.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Don't forget, it's a new user! ;-) (Hi, Pops!)

Comment: @SeanAllred This is a poll, our -1 rule does not apply in this case I think since the votes are supposed to declare your personal opinion.

Comment: I think the simplest or most intuitive way to express one's opinion would be to _upvote_ one of the two answers posted by Pops. Of course, upvoting one option and downvoting the other one makes double the difference, so if you really feel strongly about this question...

Comment: @yo' I know – the comment was supposed to be funny :)