# If I travel to a TUG conference, can I get a TeX.SX T-shirt?

Tags: support, site-promotion, tug

If I get to be a TUG member [associated with the StackExchange membership](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/annual-tex-user-group-membership-question-2015-edition) and I travel to the TUG conference in Darmstadt, can I get a TeX.SX T-shirt somehow in order to promote the fact that StackExchange in an institutional member of TUG? I thought of buying it, but unfortunately [the SE Store has been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580).

*Edited by Paulo: and while you guys are on the T-shirt subject:*

[image: Quack]

*Quack!*

Comment: SE has provided stuff to users attending conferences in the past, I'd suggest to contact them directly using the "contact us" link in the footer.

Comment: I think I still have a TeX.SE T-shirt, size M (too small for me, hence never worn), and I would be happy to send it to you. :-)

Comment: @Mico Size M for a guy 6'0" (183 cm)? Doesn't seem to work... :D

Comment: OK, somebody else will have to claim it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *theory*, yes.

In practice, I'm not sure how much TeX SE swag we have left in the warehouse, or if there's any at all. (The original print run for this site was before I joined the company.)

The best thing to do is what Mad Scientist said: [contact us](https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) using the "Other" option, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pops. If I go there, I'll hit you a message.

Comment: Just one thing: If I remember correctly, I can't print the T-shirt myself, no matter what... or can I?

Comment: It's worth mentioning, legally, that representatives are "official".  (This of course is still dependent on StackExchange's specific decision.)

Comment: @yo' it's a pretty gray area. If you just want a shirt to wear around the house, [it's not that big a deal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74835/using-logo-to-make-myself-a-t-shirt), but as you move towards situations where people might think you're an employee or otherwise representing the company, it gets less okay.

Comment: @Pops Well, my points are two: (1) it's cheaper to buy one and print it here than to even send it from abroad, (2) if you don't have any on stock, I would still like one. Anyways, it's a pointless discussion now. I should start solving the problems only once I reach them :)