# “From Answers to Packages”: Things to do before a release.

Tags: discussion, tex-sx-package

Andrew [suggested](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/birthday-celebrations/1432#1432) to release the first version of the [TeX.SX package](https://launchpad.net/tex-sx) on CTAN as a birthday celebration for TeX.SX. Before this can happen there are still a few things that need to be done.

I'll create a separate answer for each ToDo item. That way any potential discussion can stay localized. Whenever a task is completed, the corresponding “answer” can simply be deleted. Please add any additional things that need to be done/decided.

Comment: I hope I don't trigger any abuse detection algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

## Scoping

Any private macros need to be scoped (with which prefix)? Any public macros should be named in such a way that they are unlikely to conflict with another package. The same holds for pgfkeys handlers (I'd suggest putting them into a separate folder, instead of simply into `/pgf/` or `/tikz/`).

Answer (score 0):

## Testing

Make sure that everything works as expected.

Comment: Add your name to the list of testers [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/tikz-pgf-answer-package-part-2/1251#1251)

Answer (score 0):

## Readme file

Add a README file, that is displayed in the CTAN listing.

Answer (score 0):

## Documentation

Make sure everything is documented. Should the documentation of the individual subpackages/libraries be put together into a single file? If so, we also need an introduction.

Comment: Volunteer to help with documentation [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/tikz-pgf-answer-package-part-2/1251#1251)

Answer (score 0):

## Versioning

Decide on a versioning scheme for future releases.

Answer (score 0):

## Test PGF version

The package should test the pgf version and emit a warning if it isn't v2.10.